# K8s pod priority & outOfPods

Tags: kubernetes

we had the situation that the k8s-cluster was running out of pods after an update (kubernetes or more specific: ICP) resulting in "OutOfPods" error messages. The reason was a lower "podsPerCore"-setting which we corrected afterwards. Until then there were pods with a provided priorityClass (1000000) which cannot be scheduled. Others - without a priorityClass (0) - were scheduled. I assumed a different behaviour. I thought that the K8s scheduler would kill pods with no priority so that a pod with priority can be scheduled. Was I wrong?

Thats just a question for understanding because I want to guarantee that the priority pods are running, no matter what.

Thanks

---

Pod with Prio:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/psp: ibm-anyuid-hostpath-psp
  creationTimestamp: "2019-12-16T13:39:21Z"
  generateName: dms-config-server-555dfc56-
  labels:
    app: config-server
    pod-template-hash: 555dfc56
    release: dms-config-server
  name: dms-config-server-555dfc56-2ssxb
  namespace: dms
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: dms-config-server-555dfc56
    uid: c29c40e1-1da7-11ea-b646-005056a72568
  resourceVersion: "65065735"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/dms/pods/dms-config-server-555dfc56-2ssxb
  uid: 7758e138-2009-11ea-9ff4-005056a72568
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_USERNAME
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: username
          name: dms-config-server-git
    - name: CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: password
          name: dms-config-server-git
    envFrom:
    - configMapRef:
        name: dms-config-server-app-env
    - configMapRef:
        name: dms-config-server-git
    image: docker.repository..../infra/config-server:2.0.8
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /actuator/health
        port: 8080
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 90
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    name: config-server
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      name: http
      protocol: TCP
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /actuator/health
        port: 8080
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 20
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 250m
        memory: 600Mi
      requests:
        cpu: 10m
        memory: 300Mi
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        drop:
        - MKNOD
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-v7tpv
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  nodeName: kub-test-worker-02
  priority: 1000000
  priorityClassName: infrastructure
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure
    operator: Exists
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: default-token-v7tpv
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-v7tpv
```

Pod without Prio (just an example within the same namespace):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/psp: ibm-anyuid-hostpath-psp
  creationTimestamp: "2019-09-10T09:09:28Z"
  generateName: produkt-service-57d448979d-
  labels:
    app: produkt-service
    pod-template-hash: 57d448979d
    release: dms-produkt-service
  name: produkt-service-57d448979d-4x5qs
  namespace: dms
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: produkt-service-57d448979d
    uid: 4096ab97-5cee-11e9-97a2-005056a72568
  resourceVersion: "65065755"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/dms/pods/produkt-service-57d448979d-4x5qs
  uid: b112c5f7-d3aa-11e9-9b1b-005056a72568
spec:
  containers:
  - image: docker-snapshot.repository..../dms/produkt-    service:0b6e0ecc88a28d2a91ffb1db61f8ca99c09a9d92
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /actuator/health
        port: 8080
        scheme: HTTP
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    name: produkt-service
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      name: http
      protocol: TCP
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /actuator/health
        port: 8080
        scheme: HTTP
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    resources: {}
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        drop:
        - MKNOD
      procMount: Default
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-v7tpv
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  nodeName: kub-test-worker-02
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: default-token-v7tpv
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-v7tpv
```

Comment: There are various factors in schedular and preemption logic. If you can share the manifests for lower priority and higher priority pods, it would be useful.

Comment: What do you mean by update? Node update, deployment update?

Comment: @ShashankV I posted the yaml from the pod with prio and a yaml from an example pod without prio

Comment: @DawidKruk We updated kubernetes (we are using IBM Cloud Private). But since this seems to be a gerenal question I posted it here. We are now using K8s v1.13.9

Comment: Just to clarify: High priority pod couldn't get scheduled on node but lower priority one could. You disabled the podsPerCore parameter and then they got scheduled?

Comment: Exactly (but we increased the podsPerCore parameter so every pod could be scheduled)

Comment: From which to which version the upgrade took place?

Comment: Can you provide logs from the unscheduled pod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a lot of circumstances that will alter the work of the scheduler. There is a documentation talking about it: [Pod priority and preemption](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/).

Be aware of the fact that this features were deemed stable at version 1.14.0

From the IBM perspective please take in mind that the version 1.13.9 will be supported [**until 19 of February 2020!**](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-cs_versions).

**You are correct that pods with lower priority should be replaced with higher priority pods.**

Let me elaborate on that with an example:

### Example

Let's assume a Kubernetes cluster with 3 nodes (1 master and 2 nodes):

- By default you cannot schedule normal pods on master node
- **The only worker node that can schedule the pods has 8GB of RAM**.
- 2nd worker node has a taint that disables scheduling.

This example will base on RAM usage but it can be used in the same manner as CPU time.

#### Priority Class

There are 2 priority classes:

- zero-priority (0)
- high-priority (1 000 000)

YAML definition of zero priority class:

```
apiVersion: scheduling.k8s.io/v1
kind: PriorityClass
metadata:
  name: zero-priority
value: 0
globalDefault: false
description: "This is priority class for hello pod"
```

`globalDefault: false` is used for objects that do not have assigned priority class. It will assign this class by default.

YAML definition of high priority class:

```
apiVersion: scheduling.k8s.io/v1
kind: PriorityClass
metadata:
  name: high-priority
value: 1000000
globalDefault: false
description: "This is priority class for goodbye pod"
```

To apply this priority classes you will need to invoke:
`$ kubectl apply -f FILE.yaml`

#### Deployments

With above objects you can create deployments:

- Hello - deployment with low priority
- Goodbye - deployment with high priority

YAML definition of hello deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
      version: 1.0.0
  replicas: 10
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
        version: 1.0.0
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0"
        env:
        - name: "PORT"
          value: "50001"
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "128Mi"
      priorityClassName: zero-priority
```

Please take a specific look on this fragment:

```
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "128Mi"
      priorityClassName: zero-priority
```

It will limit number of pods because of the requested resources as well as it will assign low priority to this deployment.

YAML definition of goodbye deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: goodbye
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: goodbye
      version: 2.0.0
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: goodbye
        version: 2.0.0
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: goodbye
        image: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0"
        env:
        - name: "PORT"
          value: "50001"
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "6144Mi"
      priorityClassName: high-priority
```

Also please take a specific look on this fragment:

```
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "6144Mi"
      priorityClassName: high-priority
```

This pods will have much higher request for RAM and high priority.

#### Testing and troubleshooting

There is no enough information to properly troubleshoot issues like this. Without extensive logs of many components starting from `kubelet` to `pods`,`nodes` and `deployments` itself.

Apply `hello` deployment and see what happens: 
`$ kubectl apply -f hello.yaml`

Get basic information about the deployment with command:

`$ kubectl get deployments hello`

Output should look like that after a while:

```
NAME    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
hello   10/10   10           10          9s
```

As you can see all of the pods are ready and available. The requested resources were assigned to them.

To get more details for troubleshooting purposes you can invoke:

- `$ kubectl describe deployment hello`
- `$ kubectl describe node NAME_OF_THE_NODE`

Example information about allocated resources from the above command:

```
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests      Limits
  --------           --------      ------
  cpu                250m (12%)    0 (0%)
  memory             1280Mi (17%)  0 (0%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)        0 (0%)
```

Apply `goodbye` deployment and see what happens: 
`$ kubectl apply -f goodbye.yaml`

Get basic information about the deployments with command: 
`$ kubectl get deployments`

```
NAME      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
goodbye   1/3     3            1           25s
hello     9/10    10           9           11m
```

As you can see there is goodbye deployment but only 1 pod is available. And despite the fact that the goodbye has much higher priority, the hello pods are still working.

Why it is like that?:

`$ kubectl describe node NAME_OF_THE_NODE`

```
Non-terminated Pods:          (13 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                        CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                   ----                                        ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                     goodbye-575968c8d6-bnrjc                    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      6Gi (83%)        0 (0%)         15m
  default                     hello-fdfb55c96-6hkwp                       0 (0%)        0 (0%)      128Mi (1%)       0 (0%)         27m
  default                     hello-fdfb55c96-djrwf                       0 (0%)        0 (0%)      128Mi (1%)       0 (0%)         27m
```

Take a look at requested memory for goodbye pod. It is as described above as `6Gi`.

```
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests      Limits
  --------           --------      ------
  cpu                250m (12%)    0 (0%)
  memory             7296Mi (98%)  0 (0%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)        0 (0%)
Events:              <none>
```

The memory usage is near 100%.

Getting information about specific goodbye pod that is in `Pending` state will yield some more information `$ kubectl describe pod NAME_OF_THE_POD_IN_PENDING_STATE`:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  38s (x3 over 53s)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient memory, 2 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

Goodbye pod was not created because there were not enough resources that could be satisfied.  But there still was some left resources for hello pods.

**There is possibility for a situation that will kill lower priority pods and schedule higher priority pods.**

Change the requested memory for goodbye pod to `2304Mi`. It will allow scheduler to assign of all required pods (3):

```
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "2304Mi"
```

You can delete the previous deployment and apply new one with memory parameter changed.

Invoke command: `$ kubectl get deployments`

```
NAME      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
goodbye   3/3     3            3           5m59s
hello     3/10    10           3           48m
```

As you can see all of the goodbye pods are available.

**Hello pods got reduced to make space for pods with higher priority (goodbye)**.

Comment: Thanks @Dawid Kruk for this response! Thats sufficient for me: It seems like I understood it correctly.

Unfortunately I don't have logs since the update was in december and we fixed it quickly. I'm aware that you cannot give me a detailed answer with such poor information. It was important for me to recheck that I'm doing thinks right.