# k8 pod priorities and tests

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

These are my priority classes

```
NAME                      VALUE        GLOBAL-DEFAULT   AGE
k8-monitoring             1000000      false            4d7h
k8-system                 500000       false            4d7h
k8-user                   1000         false            4d7h
```

I am trying out a test for priorities within the confinement of namespace pod quotas, Can some confirm me, if the approach is right. If not please guide me.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: priority-test
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: priority-pod-quota
  namespace: priority-test
spec:
  hard:
    pods: "5"
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: user-priority
  namespace: priority-test
  labels:
    tier: x3
spec:
  # modify replicas according to your case
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: x3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: x3
    spec:
      priorityClassName: k8-user
      containers:
      - name: php-redis
        image: gcr.io/google_samples/gb-frontend:v3
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: system-priority
  namespace: priority-test
  labels:
    tier: x2
spec:
  # modify replicas according to your case
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: x2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: x2
    spec:
      priorityClassName: k8-system
      containers:
      - name: php-redis
        image: gcr.io/google_samples/gb-frontend:v3
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: monitoring-priority
  namespace: priority-test
  labels:
    tier: x1
spec:
  # modify replicas according to your case
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: x1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: x1
    spec:
      priorityClassName: monitoring-priority
      containers:
      - name: php-redis
        image: gcr.io/google_samples/gb-frontend:v3
```

I am running this test in EKS v.1.15 but not getting the priority that is explained as designed. Something tells me if I need to have an another eye looking at it

Should not see this, high priority should be running

```
NAME                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
monitoring-priority   3         0         0       17m
system-priority       3         2         2       17m
user-priority         3         3         3       17m
```

I have also read excellent solution given by Dawid Kruk [K8s pod priority & outOfPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59642272/k8s-pod-priority-outofpods/59681252#59681252)

Answer (score 3):

You have defined `ResourceQuota` with 5 pods as `hard` requirement. This `ResourceQuota` is applied at namespace level on all pods regardless of their priority class. Thats why you see 3 pods as `current` in  `user-priority`  and 2 pods in `current` in `system-priority`. Rest of the pods are not able to run because of the limit of 5 pods defined in `ResourceQuota`. If you check `kubectl get events` you should see `403 FORBIDDEN` error related to resource quota.

`ResourceQuota` is an admission controller which will not let pods get into the scheduling queue at all when the quota is reached which is what happening now. So you need to increase the ResourceQuota quota to proceed to the testing of pod priority and preemption.

The right way to test pod priority and preemption is to deploy enough pods to reach a nodes resource capacity and verify if low priority pods are being evicted to schedule high priority pods.

Comment: Arghya, Thank you for the reply but I am not looking for ResourceQuota my aim is to see demonstrate high priority pods evicting lower priority pods.

Comment: Remove the ResourceQuota or increase it so that pods can be scheduled.after that deploy many pods to reach the capacity of the node and see if low priority pods are being evicted to schedule high priority pods

Comment: Thank you, I tried it in an isolated cluster and was able to get things working. I guess i learnt that attempting resource quota to isolate the priority test was not going to work.

Comment: Have you found any solution to evict lower priority on quota reach?